# Use Raspberry to make a Digital Photo frame

Tags: gallery, raspberry-pi, photos

I received my first raspberry, connected to my TV everything is ok !

I would like to use it as a digital photo frame where I get a RSS feed and I display photos on TV. I don't want to use a Web slideshow but a Linux progamm written on C, C++ or Java (or something similar...).

I would like the programm to run when I switch on the PI.

Any advice about an existing RSS photo reader or photos gallery on linux ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a working picture frame with your specifications this is a good place to start: http://theswitchtolinux.blogspot.com/2012/12/raspberry-pi-daily-deviations-picture.html
To download images from RSS here is a python library for RSS parsing http://code.google.com/p/feedparser/